# Where do I find the android debug key build by Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I am building an App using jquerymobile and Phonegap. Phonegap should be adding the debug key for android build.

Can someone help me as to where I can find that key. I need the key to use with facebook App to connect with facebook.

All help appreciated

Comment: i have some problem, did you had solved this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a debug key, but need to generate a release key and attach the keystore to build.phonegap.com build for android. Steps for getting the release key are here

`http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html`

Answer (score -1):

You need to generate new keystore. Use this command to generate it inside your terminal/CMD.

```
keytool -exportcert -alias YourAppName -keystore /Desktop/YourAppNameKeyStore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```